# How do multiple fork statements work?

Tags: c, unix, fork

If I run the following code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    pid_t pid, pid1;
    fflush(stdout);
    pid = fork();
    fflush(stdout); 
    pid1 = fork();
    if(pid==0)
    {
         printf("%d is the first child\n", getpid() );
    }
    else if(pid>0)
    {
         printf("%d is the first parent\n", pid);
        wait();
    }
    if(pid1==0)
    {
         printf("%d is the second child\n", getpid() );
    }
    else if(pid1>0)
    {
         printf("%d is the second child\n", pid1);
        wait();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I get the output :

```
2896 is the first parent
2896 is the first child
2898 is the first child
2898 is the second child
2898 is the second child
2896 is the first parent
2897 is the second child
2897 is the second child
```

I cannot understand the output. Why are the same strings being printed multiple times ?

Comment: How did you conclude that there were 8 processes?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are doing total 3 forks: First, `pid = fork()` is done in original process, resulting in one more process, so total is now two, both continuing from the next line in your code.

Then `pid1 = fork()` is done on both of these, resulting in two *more* child processes, so total is now 4, each again continuing to next line (first if).

Then all three processes process the two if-else statements (assuming no fork errors), each process printing two lines. So four processes times 2 lines is 8 lines. Which you are getting.

So the processes are:

- original
- first generation older child, from 1st fork statement
- first generation younger child, from 2nd fork statement by the original
- 2nd generation child, from 2nd fork statement by the older first generation child

If you want to understand the output, step through the code in your mind for all of these four processes. It might also help if you print out current pid in each print statement, in addition to what you print now.

Comment: What will be the value of `pid` after the second fork in the newly created processes ?

Comment: @AshRj 2nd fork is done twice, in original and in 1st child. When first fork returned (in two processes), the original process assigned pid of 1st child to `pid` variable, while 1st child assigned `0` to it. This value will remain in the processes produced by 2nd fork statement.

Comment: Well, FWIW, I think it is pretty rare that you do fork like that, where parent and child continue executing same code. It's more common that there is immediate `if`, and parent and child code paths are different from then on.

Comment: Yes, I realise that. This was sort of a derivative of an assignment question.

Comment: I visualised it in the form of a tree. Completely clear now :)

Comment: Well just a side note, i run the same program but get a different output.

Comment: What about this program?

    void main()
    {
     printf("\nBefore");
     fork();
     printf("\nAfter");
    }

Following the same logic for continuing from the forked statement it should print: "Before, After, After". It actually prints: "Before, After, Before, After".

Comment: OK, I (kind of) got it. The output is garbled because of how printf works. If I add the new lines at the end of both strings, they print exactly as expected. Anyways, learned two things here!, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For better understanding, you can write your if/else block for each process:

```
    if(pid != 0 && pid1 != 0){
        printf("Parent P\n");//parent
    }else if(pid == 0 && pid1 != 0){
        printf("First child of P\n");
    }else if(pid != 0 && pid1 == 0){
        printf("Second child of P\n");
    }else{
        //pid = 0, pid2 = 0
        printf("Child of the first child of P\n");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Also i think you print same string mistakenly in this code below

```
else if(pid1>0)
{
    printf("%d is the second child\n", pid1); // This "child" should be "parent"
    wait();
}
```